# Pass service name on gcloud beta run deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am using the new way to deploy google cloud run (and loving!) but how can I pass the service name on the command?

I saw the docs but nothing related.

```
gcloud beta run deploy --source .                                 
Service name: my-cloud-run-name
```

How can I pass the service name **by** the command line? Something like:

```
gcloud beta run deploy --name my-cloud-run-name --source .
```

Comment: What is your problem? What have you tried? What is the error? Edit your question to be useful for others. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: My problem is the cli asking for the `Service name`, I want to pass this too by command line.

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I still do not understand your problem. To specify the service name put it on the command line: `gcloud run deploy SERVICE-NAME`.

Comment: Ah, was it then? :( I tried so many things except this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a positional argument: `gcloud beta run deploy SERVICE-NAME --source .`

Comment: `gcloud beta run deploy` is much better, great job GCP team

Comment: @steren Thanks for the easy command now. Earlier we are making a container on gcr.io and used to take more time. For every push with the above command, will the old gcr containers get cleaned up?